# Как настроить Nginx для запуска бота на вебхуках?

Tags: nginx, aiogram, развертывание, webhook

Арендовал домен, зарегистрировал, настроил днс и тд. Получил ssl при помощи letsencrypt. Запускаю на сервере тг бота на вебхуках и не понимаю как мне настроить nginx, так что бы он направлял запросы с моего домена на какой то локальный айпишник того же сервера, например 127.0.0.1:8080, для прослушки телеграмом.